# Virtual keyboard on pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, virtual-keyboard, qtvirtualkeyboard

How do I create a qtVirtualKeyBoard on python? Is it necessary a enterprise Qt version?
I’ve been trying to create my own keyboard but it wasn’t good and beautiful to see..

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Consider asking more granular questions. Your question is a bit too vague to be answered in StackOverflow. Do have a read at `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask` and perhaps update your question so that you can get better answers

Comment: The license part of the question is off-topic in SO.